# Right way of preparing address for google map json geocode

Tags: php, google-maps

I am trying to get lat and lng values from an address using the following PHP script:

```
    $address = "G & D KOI & AQUARIA, KLEINE VELD, DALEN, Nederland";
    $prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);
    $prepAddr = str_replace('&','%26',$prepAddr);
    $geocode = file_get_contents('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
    $output= json_decode($geocode);
    $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $lng = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
```

**I am replacing `&` with `%26`. and ' ' with '+'. Do I need to take care of anything else?**

Comment: You need to get api key from google.

Comment: I didn't know they could show wrong data for not having key. Added the key and it fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$prepAddr = urlencode($prepAddr);
```

and use the `$prepAddr` in your API code just like you are using.

**urlencode — URL-encodes string**

```
string urlencode ( string $str )
```

This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I wanted.